# Origin of the word “Männin”

Tags: word-usage, etymology

So, I was reading the Schlachter-Bibel in German and I found this very interesting verse (linguistically):

> Da sprach der Mensch: Das ist nun einmal Bein von meinem Bein und Fleisch von meinem Fleisch! Die soll Männin heißen; denn sie ist dem Mann entnommen!

I had never heard the word *Männin* before and I wondered if perhaps it was coined for this very verse. Because in Hebrew,

> She shall be called *isha* because she was taken out of *ish*

makes sense because the word for *woman* is derived from *man*. Conveniently it is the same in English, so no special considerations are needed. In German, saying

> Die soll Frau heißen; denn sie ist dem Mann entnommen

doesn’t really make sense. Or any of the other common words for *woman*. I found this in the Luther bible too. Does anyone know if this word was used before then? (It’s also never used again in the bible). Doing a google search on the word returns very few results. One of them being a 2015 Movie.

Since my question is kind of lost in all the background I gave, I want to clarify-restate it. Was männin coined specifically for this verse or did it have prior usage?

Comment: So TIL where the slang word "die Ische" (for a young woman) might come from.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Grimms write in their dictionary:

> **Männin:**
>   genossin des mannes. die bildung dieses wortes aus mann erfolgt wol zufrühest in der geistlichen sprache für übertragung der vulgatastelle genes. 2, 23: **haec vocabitur virago, quoniam de viro sumpta est**, wo bereits ahd. glossen virago commanin (aus dem zusammengesetzten comman vir) gewähren, vgl. Steinmeyer und Sievers ahd. gloss. 1, 311, 58, wie denn die bibel von 1483 die stelle gibt: *dise wirt genennet ein mennin, wann sy ist genomen von dem mann; Luther: man wird sie mennin heiszen, darumb das sie vom manne genomen ist;* <sup>[Grimm](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&lemid=GM01178)</sup>

According to this the term *Männin* resulted from Bible translations of the original Latin **virago**. They say further that it was present in Old High German already (*commanin*). Later the term was also used outside of a religious context but in modern German you will only find remnants in composite nouns:

> die Herrin des Hauses ... sie ist beinahe Ihre **Landsmännin**, sie ist eine Französin. <sup>Thomas Mann: Buddenbrooks</sup>

Comment: Or to induce a comedic effect along the lines of *Männer und Männinnen* (analogous to *Herren und Herrinnen*)

Comment: See http://www.bibleserver.com/text/EU.LUT.SLT.GNB/1.Mose2,23 and the comments there. "Männin" seems really to be a word created especially to represent that verse in the bible in german.

Comment: Die Funktion, die in Deutschland »Ministerpräsident« heißt, heißt in Österreich »Landeshauptmann« (politisches Oberhaupt eines Bundeslandes). Als 1996 mit Waltraud Klasnic erstmals in Österreich eine Frau zum Landeshauptmann eines Bundeslandes (nämlich der Steiermark) gewählt wurde, lehnte es Frau Klasnic strikt ab, als »Landeshauptfrau« bezeichnet zu werden. Einige Zeit lang wurde daher darüber diskutiert, ob man Frau Klasnic nun als »Landeshaupt**männin** der Steiermark« oder doch als »Frau Landeshauptmann der Steiermark« bezeichnen sollte. Klasnic selbst bestand auf »Frau Landeshauptmann«.

Comment: It's not only linked to the latin Bible translation (the vulgata), but it the words for man and woman are akready very similar in the original hebrew text. Many German editions of the Bible contain a footnote at this point, essentially saying "Luther uses the word 'Männin' to replicate a hebrew pun".